# Moving a QLabel via drag and drop

Tags: qt

If I have a `QLabel` which displays an image:

```
QImage image("1.jpg");
ui->label_1->setGeometry(QRect(0,0,0,0));
ui->label_1->setpixmap(QPixmap("1.jpg",0,QT::Autocolor));
ui->label_1->adjustsize();
```

How can I drag and drop it? Is it possible to move the label?

Comment: Are you just trying to move it around inside of the same parent QObject? Are you trying to move it around the desktop? or between two QObject parents?

Comment: i want to move inside the same parent Qobject